# Badges for meta on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion

Why are there badges for meta on Stack Overflow? I understand the sites are intertwined but isn't it a little redundant to have badges for a site that already has a badge system in place?

Comment: Meta badges: if only [reversals](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/41/reversal) were this easy on the regular sites...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Every meta site awards badges. It's just more noticeable on MSO since it looks and feels like a "regular" Q&A site.

The meta-related badges on the main sites, including Stack Overflow, are there to encourage meta participation. The fact that meta itself awards additional badges for participating *on* meta is somewhat irrelevant.

By and large, folks don't go looking for new sites to join just for the sake of earning more badges. (Although we have 100 sites now, so go nuts, y'all. :)) They start by getting interested in the subject and in the case of meta, the subject is site governance and moderation. If it takes a main-site badge to draw attention to meta and pique a bit of interest... sounds great to me.

Comment: If so, the meta.X.SE badges should count towards the badges on X.SE, or at least on the flair...

Comment: @vonbrand How so? Does anyone actually care about advertising their site-specific meta participation over their participation in actual Q&A? (Assuming that some folks would have more meta badges than badges on some main sites they participate on.)

Comment: @AnnaLear Well... someone cared enough to post a feature request: [Can we add Meta badges to flair?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/3640/25936)

Comment: @Yannis Oh hey, it's just a single badge count. Not per site. No idea what I was thinking earlier. Still... meta badges there feel weird to me.

Comment: I know what you mean, MSO is my top site per rep and that feels... dirty. Not really something I'd like to further advertise.

Comment: @Yannis And then there's all the ProgSE meta badges... that's just hard to admit to.

Comment: Gold [discussion] on MSO, silver on Meta ProgSE. Do I _really_ talk that much? /don't answer that.